# skip and autostart in fread

Tags: r, data.table

I am using the following code to read a file with the data.table library:

```
fread(myfile, header=FALSE, sep=",", skip=100, colClasses=c("character","numeric","NULL","numeric"))
```

but I get the following error:

```
The supplied 'sep' was not found on line 80. To read the file as a single character column set sep='\n'.
```

It says it did not find sep on line 80, however I set skip=100 so it should not pay attention to the first 100 lines.

**UPDATE:**
I tried with skip=101 and it worked but it skips the first line where the data starts

I am using version 1.9.2 of the data.table package and R version 3.02 64 bit on windows 7

Comment: Have you tried not passing `sep` and `colClasses`? `fread` should be able to determine these automatically.

Comment: Please, please, always state the version of software up front so we don't need to ask. v1.9.2 has just been released. Have you upgraded yet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We don't know the version number you're using, but I can make a guess in this case.

Try setting `autostart=101`.

Note the first paragraph of Details in `?fread` :

> Once the separator is found on line `autostart`, the number of columns is determined. Then the file is searched backwards from `autostart` until a row is found that doesn't have that number of columns. Thus, the first data row is found and any human readable banners are automatically skipped. This feature can be particularly useful for loading a set of files which may not all have consistently sized banners. Setting `skip>0` overrides this feature by setting `autostart=skip+1` and turning off the search upwards step.

the `skip` argument has :

> If -1 (default) use the procedure described below starting on line autostart to find the first data row. skip>=0 means ignore autostart and take line skip+1 as the first data row (or column names according to header="auto"|TRUE|FALSE as usual). skip="string" searches for "string" in the file (e.g. a substring of the column names row) and starts on that line (inspired by read.xls in package gdata).

and the `autostart` argument has :

> Any line number within the region of machine readable delimited text, by default 30. If the file is shorter or this line is empty (e.g. short files with trailing blank lines) then the last non empty line (with a non empty line above that) is used. This line and the lines above it are used to auto detect sep, sep2 and the number of fields. It's extremely unlikely that autostart should ever need to be changed, we hope.

In your case perhaps the human readable header is much larger than 30 rows, which is why I guess setting `autostart=101` might work. No need to use `skip`.

One motivation is for convenience when a file contains multiple tables. By setting `autostart` to any row inside the table that you want to pluck out of the file, it'll find the first data row and header row for you automatically, and then read just that table. You don't have to worry about getting the exact line number at the start of data like you do with `skip`. `fread` can only read one table currently. It could feasibly return a list of tables from a single file, but that's getting a bit complicated and nobody has asked for that.

Comment: thanks for your responde. I tried with autostart=102 and it worked.

Comment: Hi Matt, I came across this answer for my similar problem with `fread` however, the answer doesn't seem to apply.  If you have sufficient time, I would appreciate your help here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24759346/fread-skip-and-autostart-issue

Comment: @Matt Dowle is there no way to skip some rows (e.g. the first 1000) and at the same time change column classes via `colClasses`? Because this is what I need when I try to read a file in chunks

Comment: @EDC I think that should work. Please try `fread` from dev and see [news](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/NEWS.md). If it doesn't work let me know via a GitHub issue. `fread` has been overhauled in dev so it's only worth discussing the dev version at the current time.

Comment: 'autostart' is now deprecated and ignored. Consider skip='string' or skip=n