# fread skip and autostart issue

Tags: r, data.table, fread

I have the following code:

```
raw_test <- fread("avito_test.tsv", nrows = intNrows, skip = intSkip)
```

Which produces the following error:

```
Error in fread("avito_test.tsv", nrows = intNrows, skip = intSkip, autostart = (intSkip +  : 
  Expected sep (',') but new line, EOF (or other non printing character) ends field 14 on line 1003 when detecting types: 10066652  Ð¢Ñ€Ð°Ð½ÑÐ¿Ð¾Ñ€Ñ‚   ÐÐ²Ñ‚Ð¾Ð¼Ð¾Ð±Ð¸Ð»Ð¸ Ñ Ð¿Ñ€Ð¾Ð±ÐµÐ³Ð¾Ð¼  Nissan R Nessa, 1998    Ð¢Ð°Ñ€Ð°Ð½Ñ‚Ð°Ñ Ð² Ð¾Ñ‚Ð»Ð¸Ñ‡Ð½Ð¾Ð¼ ÑÐ¾ÑÑ‚Ð¾ÑÐ½Ð¸Ð¸. Ð½Ð° Ð¿Ñ€Ð¾ÑˆÐ»Ð¾Ð¹ Ð½ÐµÐ´ÐµÐ»Ðµ Ð²Ð¾Ð·Ð¸Ð»Ð¸ Ð½Ð° Ñ‚ÐµÑ…. ÐžÐ±ÑÐ»ÑƒÐ¶Ð¸Ð²Ð°Ð½Ð¸Ðµ. Ð’ Ð´Ð¾Ñ€Ð¾Ð¶Ð½Ñ‹Ñ… Ð½ÐµÐ¿Ñ€Ð¸ÑÑ‚Ð½Ð¾ÑÑ‚ÑÑ… Ð½Ðµ Ð±Ñ‹Ð» ÑƒÑ‡Ð°ÑÑ‚Ð½Ð¸ÐºÐ¾Ð¼. Ð”ÐµÑ‚Ð°Ð»Ð¸ ÐºÑƒÐ·Ð¾Ð²Ð° Ð±ÐµÐ· ÐºÐ¾Ñ†Ð¾Ðº Ð¸ Ñ‚ÐµÑ€Ð¾Ðº. ÐŸÑ€ÐµÐ´Ð½Ð°Ð·Ð½Ð°Ñ‡Ð°Ð»Ð°ÑÑŒ Ð´Ð»Ñ Ð¿Ð¾ÐµÐ·Ð´Ð¾Ðº Ð½Ð° Ð¿Ñ€Ð¸Ñ€Ð¾Ð´Ñƒ, ÐžÑ‚Ð´Ð°Ð¼ Ñ‚Ð¾Ð»ÑŒÐºÐ¾ Ð² Ð´Ð¾Ð±Ñ€Ñ‹Ðµ Ñ€ÑƒÐºÐ¸. Ð’ ÑÐ°Ð»Ð¾Ð½ Ð½Ðµ Ð¿Ð¾ÑÑ‚Ð°Ð²Ð»ÑŽ Ð½Ðµ Ð·Ð²Ð¾Ð½Ð¸Ñ‚Ðµ    "{""ÐœÐ°Ñ€ÐºÐ°"":""Nissan"", ""ÐœÐ¾Ð´ÐµÐ»ÑŒ"":""R Nessa"", ""Ð“Ð¾Ð´ Ð²Ñ‹Ð¿ÑƒÑÐºÐ°"":""1998"", ""ÐŸÑ€Ð¾Ð±ÐµÐ³"":""180 000 - 189 999"", ""Ð¢Ð¸Ð¿ ÐºÑƒÐ·Ð¾Ð²Ð°"":""ÐœÐ¸Ð½Ð¸Ð²ÑÐ½"", ""Ð¦Ð²ÐµÑ‚"":""ÐžÑ€Ð°Ð½Ð¶ÐµÐ²Ñ‹Ð¹"", ""ÐžÐ±ÑŠÑ‘Ð¼ Ð´Ð²Ð¸Ð³Ð°Ñ‚ÐµÐ»Ñ"":""2.4"", ""ÐšÐ¾Ñ€Ð¾Ð±ÐºÐ° Ð¿ÐµÑ€ÐµÐ´Ð°Ñ‡"":""ÐœÐµÑ…Ð°Ð½Ð¸Ñ‡ÐµÑÐºÐ°Ñ
```

I have tried changing it to this:

```
raw_test <- fread("avito_test.tsv", nrows = intNrows, skip = intSkip, autostart = (intSkip + 2))
```

Which is based on what I read on a similar question [skip and autostart in fread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22086780/skip-and-autostart-in-fread?rq=1)

However, it produces a similar error as above.

How can I skip the first 1000 rows, and read the next thousand?  My expected output is 1000 rows total, skipping the first thousand from my CSV file, and reading the second thousand.

**Note:** Reading the file with `raw_test <- fread("avito_test.tsv", nrows = 1000, skip = -1)` works well for getting me only the first thousand, but I am trying to get only the second thousand.

**Edit:** The data is publicly available at http://www.kaggle.com/c/avito-prohibited-content/data

**Edit:** Environment and package info:

```
> packageVersion("data.table")
[1] ‘1.9.3’
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.1.0 (2014-04-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
```

Comment: According to the error message, the error occurs on line 1003. Perhaps you could provide example data, or more specifically, lines 995 to 1005 of your data file?

Comment: @tophcito It's a huge file (over 3gb) so I am not sure how to open it.  Since I can easily read 100k lines (including the "erroenous" line 1003) I don't think it's a problem with that line, rather, the problem is likely due to my misuse of the `fread` method.

Comment: Well, the error message indicates that on line 1003 there is a character that R has difficulties to interpret. It looks quite like an encoding problem to me. Without looking at a line that is read without troubles and line 1003, it's kind of hard to tell. That is, I don't see any obvious mistakes in your call to `fread()`. On Linux, a combination of `head` and `tail` could be used to cut out quickly and ugly a couple of lines from your file.

Comment: I am on Windows.  If I do `fread("avito_test.tsv", nrows = 100000, skip = -1)` it reads that line without issue.

Comment: @tophcito The data is publicly available at http://www.kaggle.com/c/avito-prohibited-content/data if you can offer any assistance.

Comment: Which version of data.table are you using?

Comment: @MattDowle I am using data.table ‘1.9.3’

Comment: Ok I'll take a look...

Comment: @MattDowle I looked around the internet again and it seems there were some similar bugs with the Windows version, but they were said to have been fixed in subsequent releases.  I am not sure how to proceed, but I would really like to complete my project!  I appreciate any help you can offer.

Comment: The entire file of 1,351,242 rows loads fine for me. Did you realise that?  It's less than 1GB in RAM. Why do you want to load in batches when it's pretty small?  Or was this just a small example.

Comment: @MattDowle You are exactly correct - I can load the entire file without issue.  However, I need smaller batches because I need to create a text corpus and DTM from this data, then run a naive Bayes classifier.  If I do that with 1m+ rows, R will freeze since I don't have sufficient RAM.  I can only do batches of 100k.  Can you help me load just 100k records via data.table instead of loading all of them?  Or maybe I can just load all of them but create a new variable that only takes 100k...  I think that may be the obvious work around.