# data.table fread, how to read in csv file last N rows

Tags: r, csv, data.table, fread

Hі!
Can someone show on the example of iris.csv  how to load the last 10 rows with the `fread` function from the `data.table`
thanks

udp=====

```
write.csv(iris,"C:\\Users\\TARAS\\Desktop\\iris.csv")
data.table::fread(cmd="tail -10 C:/Users/TARAS/Desktop/iris.csv")

"tail" ­Ґ пў«пҐвбп ў­гваҐ­­Ґ© Ё«Ё ў­Ґи­Ґ©
Є®¬ ­¤®©, ЁбЇ®«­пҐ¬®© Їа®Ја ¬¬®© Ё«Ё Ї ЄҐв­л¬ д ©«®¬.
Null data.table (0 rows and 0 cols)
```

read.csv work fine

```
ir <- read.csv("C:\\Users\\TARAS\\Desktop\\iris.csv")
> head(ir)
  X Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
1 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
2 2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
3 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
4 4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
5 5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
6 6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa
```

upd2=====

```
fpath = "C:/Users/TARAS/Desktop/iris.csv"
 fread(cmd=paste0("tail -10 '", fpath, "'"))
```

also i tried  `\` ,  `\\` ,  `/` , `//` ,

```
"tail" ­Ґ пў«пҐвбп ў­гваҐ­­Ґ© Ё«Ё ў­Ґи­Ґ©
Є®¬ ­¤®©, ЁбЇ®«­пҐ¬®© Їа®Ја ¬¬®© Ё«Ё Ї ЄҐв­л¬ д ©«®¬.



Null data.table (0 rows and 0 cols)
Warning messages:
1: In (if (.Platform$OS.type == "unix") system else shell)(paste0("(",  :
  '(tail -10 'C:/Users/TARAS/Desktop/iris.csv') > C:\Users\TARAS\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpcDiW2w\file108833c6463' execution failed with error code 1
2: In fread(cmd = paste0("tail -10 '", fpath, "'")) :
  File 'C:\Users\TARAS\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpcDiW2w\file108833c6463' has size 0. Returning a NULL data.table.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [skip and autostart in fread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22086780/skip-and-autostart-in-fread)

Comment: what operating system? In Linux or Max you can use `wc -l` to count total number of lines. Then subtract 10 from that to get the `skip` value for `fread`.  Should be able to install `wc` on Windows too.  Alternativey, if your file is not too large, you can read the whole thing, then use `tail(dt, 10)`

Comment: Honestly, I did not find the answer in this link. My OS is windows 10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have `fread` read the last n rows of a .csv using `cmd` param

```
fread(cmd="tail -10 iris.csv")
```

If you want the header information also, you can wrap the above in a call to `data.table::setnames`, where the names are obtained by reading the file without any rows (`nrows=0`):

```
setnames(
  fread(cmd="tail -10 iris.csv"),
  names(fread("iris.csv",nrows = 0))
)
```

If you have full path, you can do this:

```
fpath = "C:/Users/xxxx/Desktop/folder 1/iris.csv"

setnames(
  fread(cmd=paste0("tail -10 '", fpath, "'")),
  names(fread(fpath,nrows = 0))
)[]
```

Comment: won't this skip the header information?

Comment: yes, you are right @dww, thank you for the tip - see update

Comment: Thank you, this seems to be what you need, but how do I specify the path to the file?  @data.table::fread(cmd="tail -10  C:\\....Desktop\\iris.csv")@

Comment: This should work: `fread(cmd="tail -10 C:/Users/xxx/Desktop/iris.csv")`

Comment: can you show a complete example @
data.table::fread(cmd="tail -10",
                  file  = "C:\\Users......Desktop\\iris.csv")@  not work (

Comment: try with the slashes in unix style, not Windows, even if you are on Windows / also, you don't need the quotes after -10.. cmd is one single  string parameter - also see my edit, for a fully qualified path

Comment: see my upd please

Comment: sorry, I can't replicate your error. I'm using Windows 11, R version 4.1.0, and data.table version 1.14.2, and I can use either double backslashes, or single forward slashes, without any problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246115/discussion-between-langtang-and-mr-t).